# How to install laravel collective on laravel v5.8.37?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

When I try to install Laravel Collectives on Laravel v5.8.37 I get the following issue stating that to remove laravel/framework 5.8.37. Does someone able to resolve this issue? I tried updating composer but nothing helped.

```
sing version ^6.1 for laravelcollective/html
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - laravelcollective/html 6.x-dev requires illuminate/view ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2].
    - laravelcollective/html v6.1.0 requires illuminate/view ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2].
    - don't install illuminate/view 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/view 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
      .............................................................................
    - don't install illuminate/view v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - don't install illuminate/view v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.37, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.37].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html ^6.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[6.x-dev, v6.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: What **exactly** is unclear about the given message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

laravel collective 6.1 is not compatible with laravel 5.8 which you are using you have to install laravel collective 5.8 using

```
composer require laravelcollective/html:5.8
```